# Unable to use -C of grep in Unix Shell Script

Tags: unix, scripting, grep

I am able to use `grep` in normal command line.

```
grep "ABC" Filename -C4
```

This is giving me the desired output which is 4 lines above and below the matched pattern line.

But if I use the same command in a Unix shell script, I am unable to grep the lines above and below the pattern. It is giving me output as  the only lines where pattern is matched and an error in the end that cannot says cannot open `grep` : `-C4`

The results are similar if I use `-A4` and `-B4`

Comment: update your Q with the output of `uname -srv` . I betting you're using an old version of SunOS (or many others) where the `-[ABC]` options where not available. But as it works on the cmd line for you, you need to type `which grep` and then use that full path like `/path/to/ABCgrep/grep` in your script OR override your PATH setting like `export PATH="/path/to/ABCgrep/grep:$PATH"` . Good luck.

Comment: Put options before file names: `grep -C4 "ABC" Filename`.  If that doesn't work either, then you're running a different `grep` from the one that the shell script runs — you need to find the right path for the `grep` you use and use that in the script.  The `-A`, `-B` and `-C` options are GNU extensions; the o/s command may not support them.  You didn't identify the platform you're using — if it's Linux, that won't be the problem, but if it is Solaris or AIX or HP-UX, it could be the problem.  Since you didn't use a Linux tag, it probably isn't Linux that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you need a portable POSIX solution without the GNU extensions (`-C NUM`, `-A NUM`, and `-B NUM` are all GNU, as are arguments following the pattern and/or file name).

[POSIX grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) can't do this, but [POSIX awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) can.  This can be invoked as e.g. `grepC -C4 "ABC" Filename` (assuming it is named "grepC", is executable, and is in your `$PATH`):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

die() { echo "$*\nUsage: $0 [-C NUMBER] PATTERN [FILE]..." >&2; exit 2; }

CONTEXT=0  # default value

case $1 in
  -C  ) CONTEXT="$2"; shift 2 ;;        # extract "4" from "-C 4"
  -C* ) CONTEXT="${1#-C}"; shift ;;     # extract "4" from "-C4"
  --|-) shift ;;                        # no args or use std input (implicit)
  -*  ) [ -f "$1" ] || die "Illegal option '$1'" ;;  # non-option non-file
esac

[ "$CONTEXT" -ge 0 ] 2>/dev/null || die "Invalid context '$CONTEXT'"
[ "$#" = 0 ] && die "Missing PATTERN"

PATTERN="$1"
shift

awk '
  /'"$PATTERN"'/ {
    match='$CONTEXT'
    for(i=1; i<=CONTEXT; i++) if(NR>i) print last[i];
    print
    next
  }
  match { print; match-- }
  { for(i='$CONTEXT'; i>1; i--) last[i] = last[i-1]; last[1] = $0 }
' "$@"
```

This sets up `die` as a fatal error function, then finds the desired lines of context from your arguments (either `-C NUMBER` or `-CNUMBER`), with an error for unsupported options (unless they're files).

If the context is not a number or there is no pattern, we again fatally error out.

Otherwise, we save the pattern, shift it away, and reserve the rest of the options for handing to awk as files (`"$@"`).

There are three stanzas in this awk call:

1. Match the pattern itself.  This requires ending the single-quote portion of the string in order to incorporate the `$PATTERN` variable (which may not behave correctly if imported via `awk -v`).  Upon that match, we store the number of lines of context into the `match` variable, loop through the previous lines saved in the `last` hash (if we've gone far enough to have had them), and print them.  We then skip to the next line without evaluating the other two stanzas.
2. If there was a match, we need the next few lines for context.  As this stanza prints them, it decrements the counter.  A new match (previous stanza) will reset that count.
3. We need to save previous lines for recalling upon a match.  This loops through the number of lines of context we care about and stores them in the `last` hash.  The current line (`$0`) is stored in `last[1]`.